# How to include chutzpah test cases in tests project to output folder

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, tfs, build-process, chutzpah

I have a web project, say 'WebProj' in which I have defined all the my javascript source files with angular code. I am defining my chutzpah unit test cases for those javascript source files in another project 'WebProj.Tests' along with my other C# test cases. I am having both the web and tests project under same solution.

My problem is that when I try to integrate the web project to the TFS build process I cannot run the chutzpah test cases as the web project output folder don't have the chutzpah test case files copied to the project output folder. At the same time the test cases are executed if I have the chutzpah test cases defined in the same web project.

How can I execute the javascript chutzpah test cases on build process if those are defined in a separate Test project and include them in project output folder after build?

Answer (score 1):

To have the test case files copied to the build output folder, you need to right-click the .js file and select Properties -> set the **Copy to Output Directory** property to be **Copy always**.

Additionally, you need to follow the steps below to run chutzpah tests in TFS build process.

1. Install [jasmine.js](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jasmine-js/) to the test project.
2. Install [Chutzpah Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8741f04-bae4-4900-81c7-7c9bfb9ed1fe)
3. Install [Chutzpah test runner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chutzpah/) to the solution (on solution level, not project level).
4. Set the test assembly to match your javascript test naming convention. e.g. ***.tests.js
5. Configure to use the custom test adapter during TFS build process. 1). If you are working with vNext build, go to **Visual Studio Test** step, set the **Path to Custom Test Adapters** property to be similar to  $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages (get the path via NuGet restore); 2). If you are working with XAML build, go to **Build** –> **Manage Build Controllers**, set **Version Control Path to custom Assemblies** to the package path.

Completed steps can be found on the "But what if you want run Jasmine.JS test?" part in this blog: http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2015/09/23/Running-nUnit-and-JasmineJS-unit-tests-in-TFSVSO-vNext-build.aspx

And also this blog (do not follow the Step2 to check in these files into TFS version control, instead use NuGet to donwload these packages.) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But my issue is still not resolved. On deploying my web project using the TFS build process template I need to run my JS test cases as well which are in a separate project.  But these chutzpah unit test case files are not getting executed or processed by the task runners since the files cannot be found in output directory. Enabling 'Copy Always' property for JS files didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Add another Visual Studio Test step to your build definition that just runs the JavaScript tests as shown below; the redacted portion in the green box of the Test step is the path to your test files. When the build runs, the stats from the two test runs will be combined in the build output. [image: Visual Studio Online Build definition]